# Generating search query having problem

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql database ...

I have a table with col name food_type
in this field all the food types are in comma separated.
Now my problem is that i want to get the search result from them.
**For Example**:
Data in food_type col is like  `BBQ,Fast Food,Desi,Seafood,Vegetarian,`
And I want to search `BBQ,Seafood`.  But it can't give me the accurate result .
i try to use `like` in my sql query but same result :-(
How can I achieve this .

Comment: normalize your database and avoid such problems from the beginning

Comment: @knitti: But now what can i do . while i have a very large database

Comment: One reason more to follow knittl's advice. :) Use a programming language, explode your strings and create a record for each item.

Comment: @nick: But it slow my progress...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could even use find_in_set() function

```
select * from table
where find_in_set('bbq',field_name) and find_in_set('Seafood',field_name)
```

but, as already written, your table needs to be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 LIKE queries:

```
select * from table where field like "bbq" and field like "seafood"
```